# Python 3 MySQL sql syntax error in formatted string

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7, mysql-8.0

I'm having a play with tkinter and MySQL and I am getting an error when I try and select things from the database. I have a feeling this error is going to have something to do with my limited sql and/or tkinter experience...

So, I have a tkinter button call a function called "testUserCredentials":

```
# Creating the login button, giving it the text "Log In", and
btnLogIn = ttk.Button(self, text="Log In", command=lambda:
                      testUserCredentials(uNameTb.get(),
                      pwdTb.get()))
```

As I understand it, the .get() method grabs the text that the user enters into the text box. 
testUserCredentials(uName, password) is then called, and in this case, uName should equal "AbbieH" and password should be "pui8Aifi". The function does the following:

```
def testUserCredentials(uName, password):

query = ("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = %s, password = %s")
args = (uName, password)

sqlResult = sendSqlQuery(query, args)
```

This then runs the function I have to handle communication with the MySQL Database:

```
# Function for sending SQL queries to the MySQL database, accepts the query to
# be sent as a string
def sendSqlQuery(query, args):
    try:
        # Creating the connection string and parsing the details of which server
        # User to use, their password, the host for the connector to look at,
        # and lastly which database for them
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='hireOut',
                                      password='>5/>£7(OW-1Bo>9e',
                                      host='localhost',
                                      database='hireout')

        # Creating a cursor to be able to iterate through any results that are
        # parsed back from the query
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        # Telling the cursor to execute the query string
        cursor.execute(query, args)

        sqlResult = cursor.fetchall()

        for (username, password) in cursor:
            print("Username: %s" % username)
            print("Password: %s" % password)

        return sqlResult

        # using .is_connected() to check if the connection was made successfully
        if cnx.is_connected():
            print("Connection Established")
```

So, the error I get when I press the Log In Button is this:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', password = 'pui8Aifi'' at line 1
```

My Understanding of MySQL Syntax is that strings for the WHERE statement must be in single quotes, which is what I thought my string should be formatted as:

```
SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = 'AbbieH', password = 'pui8Aifi';
```

This string in my mind should be fine, and not throw an error... but it does...
So what am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to replace the second comma with a boolean operator keyword:
WHERE username = 'AbbieH' AND password = 'pui8Aifi';